# std::enable_if using its internal type and without using it

Tags: c++, c++11, enable-if

Why does it print "B"

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct Test
{ static void apply() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; } };

template<typename T>
struct Test<T, typename std::enable_if<true>::type>
{ static void apply() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; } };

int main()
{
    Test<int>::apply();
}
```

but this one "A"?:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct Test
{ static void apply() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; } };

template<typename T>
struct Test<T, std::enable_if<true>>
{ static void apply() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; } };

int main()
{
    Test<int>::apply();
}
```

The only difference between them is that, in the first one, I'm using `typename std::enable_it<true>::type` as `U` (e.g, `void`), but in the second one, I'm directly using `std::enable_if<true>` as `U`, which is also a well defined type and with no more meaning as `void`.

Comment: `std::enable_if<true>` has way more meaning than `void`. It is a type that has a member type named `type` that is equal to `void`. So `void` and `std::enable_if<true>` are two different things (`void`doesn't have a `type` member), `typename std::enable_if<true>::type` and `void` aren't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you write `Test<int>` you are actually writing `Test<int, void>` which will never be the same as `Test<int, std::enable_if<true>>` (though it is the same as `Test<int, typename std::enable_if<true>::type>`)

Answer (score 2):

As `typename std::enable_if<true>::type` is the same type as `void`, the first snippet is equivalent to

```
template<typename T, typename U = void>
struct Test
{ static void apply() { std::cout << "A" << std::endl; } };

template<typename T>
struct Test<T, void> // since typename std::enable_if<true>::type == void
{ static void apply() { std::cout << "B" << std::endl; } };
```

Hence, the second definition is *more specialized*, therefore if you don't provide two template arguments, the latter wins in overload resolution.

However, in the second example, you it's just a specialization for the pair of types `T` and `std::enable_if<true>`, not for `T` and `void`.
This can be checked with `std::is_same<std::enable_if<true>, void>`, which evaluates to false (clearly, `void` doesn't have a type member `type`, so it can't be the same).

Hence for the second snippet, requesting `T<int>` will match with `T<int, void>` for which only one definition is relevant, namely the first one.